# Modify class private outside class without using public method

Tags: c++

I am a C++ newbie and I need help with a strange issue (or at least its strange to me)

I have a class as such:

```
class Myclass {

    private:
        int A;
        // some other stuff...

    public:
        // constructor and stuff...
        void setA(int a);
        int* getA_addr();    
};

void Myclass::setA(int a){
    A = a;
};

int* Myclass::getA_addr(){
    return &A;
    };
```

Now, I want to modify A in main() and I am not using any other methods in the class (I did it by using extra methods and now I want to see how I can do it without using those extras). I have a function as such:

```
void change(int *ptr, int tmp){
    *ptr = tmp;
};
```

In a call to this function, I do the passing as such: `change(obj.getA_addr(), other arguments...)` where obj is an instance of Myclass.

When done in this way, I receive no compilation errors but I also can't seem to modify A (of obj). As a debug effort, I tried to print the address of A (of obj) by directly calling getA_addr(). I saw that with every call, the function returns a different address. So I am assuming that I am not passing the intended address into the function.

I have no idea why this is happening and would like to know. Also, the way I'm trying to do this is most likely not at all accurate so please, if you can provide a solution, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** [Here's the most minimal code I could come up with that reproduces the error](https://ideone.com/OVLDpN)

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_SIZE 10
using namespace std;

class Student {

private:
    int mt1;

public:
    Student();
    void setMt1(int in_mt1);
    int* getMt1();
    };

Student::Student() {};
void Student::setMt1(int in_mt1) { mt1 = in_mt1; };
int* Student::getMt1(){ return &mt1; };

class Course {
private:
    Student entries[MAX_SIZE];
    int num;

public:
    Course();
    void addStudent(Student in_student);
    Student getStudent(int index);
};

Course::Course(){ num = 0; };

void Course::addStudent(Student in_student){
    entries[num] = in_student;
    num++;
};

Student Course::getStudent(int index){ return entries[index]; };

int main() {
    void updateStudentScore(int *uscore, int newscore);

    Course mycourse;
    Student tmp_student;

    tmp_student.setMt1(60);

    mycourse.addStudent(tmp_student);

    cout<<mycourse.getStudent(0).getMt1()<<"\t"<<*mycourse.getStudent(0).getMt1()<<endl;
    updateStudentScore(mycourse.getStudent(0).getMt1(), 90);
    cout<<mycourse.getStudent(0).getMt1()<<"\t"<<*mycourse.getStudent(0).getMt1()<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void updateStudentScore(int *uscore, int newscore){
    *uscore = newscore;
};
```

I am fairly certain that my understanding of pointers and passing-by-whatevers is lacking and the way I defined functions here is creating the bug. I am sorry to inconvenience you guys. I would appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: You cannot change its value. That's the idea of `private`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. "*I also can't seem to modify A (of obj).*" is useless as a problem description; show your actual code.

Comment: @VTodorov No, that's the idea of `const`. You can modify `A` easily.

Comment: Given a pointer, though, you should be able to change the thing being pointed at.

Comment: @melpomene I meant outside the class.

Comment: @VTodorov `private` only restricts access to names. You can still modify `A` from outside if you have its address.

Comment: @VTodorov You can change any private member outside the class, when you have access to its address.

Comment: @melpomene Of course you can change anything in C++ as long as you have its address. But the idea of `private` is to restrict you from changing those values from outside of the class, isn't it?

Comment: @VTodorov No, `private` only restricts access to names.

Comment: @melpomene the actual code is lengthy (and might be unnecessarily verbose) so I feared it would be confusing. I will try to include the most relevant parts.

Comment: @VolkanMutlu Don't post incomplete snippets. Write a [mcve].

Comment: @VolkanMutlu: Whatever you include, make sure it actually reproduces the problem. What's currently here should work correctly, and we need to be able to see the problem in action.

Comment: @VolkanMutlu 1) We didn't ask for full code. We asked for [mcve]. 2) If I take the code snippets from the code you posted, and put them together into a compilable example: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://ideone.com/fY9iQO).

Comment: To change the value you defined setA. Why do you define getA_addr? Define getA as returning a value!

Comment: I edited the main question with a code that I think is expressive of the problem enough. I am certain I am overlooking something very simple. I am very, very new at this so please view the question with this in mind. Thanks for all you guys' help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your student/course code, i notice that `Course::getStudent` returns a `Student` rather than a `Student &`. Basically, that means each time you call `getStudent(x)`, you get a *temporary copy* of student `x`, whose `getMt1` function will give you a pointer to a temporary field, and any changes you make won't even survive past that statement.

If you have `getStudent` return a reference or pointer instead, your changes should persist to the Student contained in the array. (They still won't affect `tmp_student`, though, because `addStudent` copied it to add it to the array. If you want that reliably, then you need to redo quite a bit of stuff.)

Comment: Thank you! I will adjust that and see if I can translate it to the original code as a whole. There are some other stuff dependent on getStudent so it might require quite a bit of work, but I think it will be worth it. Thanks!

With the original code (as you might have guessed) the user will be able to add students and change variables contained in those Student objects, the tmp_student is something I just use to pass stuff to the entries list, I don't aim to change its values after its initial assignment. So I think I should be okay there.

Comment: @VolkanMutlu: Then you may want to reconsider how you do things. Aside from the ugliness of handing outside code pointers to your privates, right now it's way too easy to accidentally end up with a copy. You might consider a flyweight type of deal, where Students don't hold their own data but simply a container reference and index where the actual record is stored. Then, even if you copy a Student, it will still be referring to the same data.